# Select highest priority row

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle10g

Lets say I have a table with three columns, `key`, `value` and `priority` with a unique key on (`key`, `priority`).

I want to select all `key`/`value` pairs where `priority` for that key is higher than any other priority for the same `key`.

For example:

```
key | value   | priority
----------------------
'a' | 'Alice' |   5 
'a' | 'Aaron' |   10
'b' | 'Bob'   |   1
```

Should return:

```
key | value
-------------
'a' | 'Aaron'
'b' | 'Bob'
```

What's an efficient way of writing such a query?

Comment: I would like to see the answer to this...

Comment: How do you want to handle ties for the same priority

Comment: @Conrad: I'm assuming there's a unique key on `key`, `priority` so there are no ties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select [key],
       value
from (select [key],
             value,
             row_number() over(partition by [key] 
                               order by priority desc) as rn
      from YourTable) as T
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    SELECT a.`key`,
           a.`value`
      FROM tbl a
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(priority) priority,
                   `key`
              FROM tbl
          GROUP BY `key`) b ON a.`key` = b.`key`
                           AND a.priority = b.priority
```

This query will work as long as each key has one and only one priority with highest value

Answer (score 0):

Use this SQL:

```
SELECT key, value 
FROM T1 as t1
JOIN 
(SELECT key, MAX(priority) AS priority 
 FROM T1 as t2 
 GROUP BY key) as t3 
ON t1.key = t3.key AND t3.priority = t1.priority
```